# iOS emojis in TextArea

Tags: codenameone

When I enter enter an emoji in a TextArea on an iPhone, it gets rendered as a rectangle with a diagonal cross in it. But when the text of the TextArea is copied to a SpanLabel, it's rendered correctly. When running the same app on an Android phone, however, the smiley is drawn correctly both places. Bug, or something else?

Comment: This is probably an encoding issue when you translate the text back and forth or just a font you set to the text area. Things to notice: Is it rendered as an emojii while you are editing? If you type in an emojii does that work? What's the hex value of the character in question?

Comment: * Yes, it's rendered as an emoji while I'm editing. As soon as I've done, it turns into the rectangular thing

Comment: * Yes, it's rendered as an emoji while I'm editing. As soon as I've done, it turns into the rectangular thing. * If I type in colon + right parens, that doesn't get converted to en emoji. * The hex value is D83d DE00, codepoint 16F00. * The CSS for the TextArea says nothing about the font, so I assume the default font is used.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the font to system and native::MainLight see if either of those make a difference here. This sounds like a font issue. I hope the native: fonts work properly with emojiis. Did you try it with more than one iOS version? Is it happening with every emojii or with a specific set of emojiis?